# (?<=#!)(\\w+\\.*\\w+)+ doesn't match #!super.compound.key3

Tags: java, regex, lookbehind

I wrote a simple regexp

```
String s = "#!key1 #!compound.key2 #!super.compound.key3";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=#!)(\\w+\\.*\\w+)+").matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

which results in

### ACTUAL

```
key1
compound.key2
super.compound
```

and I am wondering why it matches `super.compound`, but not `super.compound.key3` as I expected.

### EXPECTED

```
key1
compound.key2
super.compound.key3
```

Any improvements to the regexp would be welcomed.

Comment: It doesn't match it because your quantified cluster looks for `\w` at beginning of each iteration and not `.`. So when it matches `super.compound` it can not match the next `.` because it expects a `\w`. Change your regex to [`(?<=#!)(?:\\w+\\.?)+`](https://regex101.com/r/s3Y390/1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use

```
(?<=#!)\w+(?:\.\w+)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ucv1nF/1) and the regex graph:

[image]

[Java test](http://ideone.com/VS8cKs):

```
String s = "#!key1 #!compound.key2 #!super.compound.key3";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=#!)\\w+(?:\\.\\w+)*").matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
// => [key1, compound.key2, super.compound.key3]
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I generate a regexp graph there?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I used https://jex.im/regulex, but it does not support lookbehinds, I edited the image manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to write this regex like this  **(?<=#!)(\\w+\\.?)+**.